# Point not plotting over a shapefile

Tags: r, gis, shapefile, r-sf, points

I am trying to plot a shapefile with Poland's Powiaty (counties) and a dot where Krakow is. This is the code that I'm using. For some reason, that dot is not appearing in the plot.

This is where I got the shapefile of Poland's Powiaty: https://www.gis-support.pl/downloads/Powiaty.zip?_ga=2.76556755.796824239.1647028537-1312541903.1646793893

```
library(sf)

# Load shapefile
poland_Powiaty <- st_read("~/Powiaty.shp")

### Krakow's coordinates
krakow <- data.frame(x=19.940000819941382, 
                     y=50.06197893970872)

point <- st_as_sf(krakow, coords = c("x", "y"))
# Set the CRS of shapefile
st_crs(point) <- "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=19 +k=0.9993 +x_0=500000 +y_0=-5300000 +ellps=GRS80
+towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs " # assign CRS to point

plot(poland_Powiaty[2])
plot(point,col="black",pch=19, cex=3,add=T)
```

[image: Output]

Does anyone know how I can be able to add Krakow to the map?

Comment: I see that you set point’s CRS. But are you sure that the polygon and point have the same CRS?

Comment: Hi John! I set the CRS that I got from crs(poland_Powiaty)

Comment: Hi @zutt you can't just set the CRS that way. You need to first set the CRS to unprojected latlong: `st_crs(point) <- '+proj=longlat'` then transform it to the CRS of `poland_powiaty` using `st_transform()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but the crs seems to be the problem.

*edited for full reprex:

```r
library(sf)
library(dplyr) #for the pipe %>%
library(ggplot2)

# data from:  https://gis-support.pl/baza-wiedzy-2/dane-do-pobrania/granice-administracyjne/
# file downloaded:  https://www.gis-support.pl/downloads/Powiaty.zip

# read shapefile, retain only geometry column
poland_Powiaty <- read_sf('Powiaty.shp') %>%  #change filename as needed
                    st_geometry()

# In latitude/longitude
krakow <- data.frame(x=19.940000819941382, 
                     y=50.06197893970872) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c('x', 'y'))

# set crs to 4326 for lat/lon
krakow <- st_set_crs(krakow, 4326)
# transform krakow to have same crs as poland_Powiaty
krakow <- st_transform(krakow, st_crs(poland_Powiaty))

# base plot
plot(poland_Powiaty)
plot(krakow, add = T, pch = 15, col = 'red')
```

[image]

```r
##  ggplot2
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = poland_Powiaty) +
  geom_sf(data = krakow, color = 'red', size = 3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hey @mrhellmann! I'm still unable to plot Krakow. With your code, I get the following after the second line: Error in UseMethod("st_crs<-") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_crs<-' applied to an object of class "data.frame"

By making a few changes to the code thanks to @qdread, I still get only the map of Poland.
```
krakow <- st_sfc(st_point(c(19.940000819941382,50.06197893970872)))
st_crs(krakow) <- '+proj=longlat'
krakow <- st_set_crs(krakow, 4326)
krakow <- st_transform(krakow, st_crs(poland_Powiaty))
plot(poland_Powiaty[2])
plot(krakow, add = T, pch = 15, col = 'red')
```

Comment: @zutt  Sorry about that, I left out the line transforming the data.frame to an sf object.  The post should work now after a quick edit.

Comment: Thanks! Now the code runs without any error, yet Krakow does not show on the map.

Comment: Since I'm not sure our shapefiles are the same, use `plot(poland_Powiaty[2])` as you did in your question, then `plot(krakow, add = T)`. Adjust the arguments for plotting krakow as needed (color, pch, cex...)

Comment: Yes, did the same. Any ideas why it wouldn't be working? It seems we are working with the same data and code.

Comment: @zutt No ideas, so I changed the answer to a full reproducible example with data sources listed. If that doesn't work for you, I'm out of ideas.